# Magento cant associate simple to configurable product

Tags: magento

I created a configurable product and went to the associated products tab and used the quick create product feature to create a bunch of products based on my configurations. However non of these products appear in the list of associated products.

I noticed that the attributes I created don't even show up on the edit product page, on either the simple, or the configurable product.

I started first by creating 3 new attributes for a configurable product I want to add, I setup the options for each one and created a new attribute set based on default that included the new attributes I created.

When I create a new simple product or configurable product, you cannot see the attributes I have created. I have tried with the attributes in the general tab as well as on their own tab. But they are never visible when you try to edit the product.

I'm suspecting the reason I can't associate the products is due to this strange problem

I'm using 1.4.2
[edited to add my work flow/screen grabs]

- http://www.buggyonpurpose.com/magento/configurable_products/01-attirubte_set.png
- http://www.buggyonpurpose.com/magento/configurable_products/02-create_configurable.png
- http://www.buggyonpurpose.com/magento/configurable_products/03-setup_configurable.png
- http://www.buggyonpurpose.com/magento/configurable_products/04-quick_create.png
- http://www.buggyonpurpose.com/magento/configurable_products/05-associate_product.png
- http://www.buggyonpurpose.com/magento/configurable_products/06-manage_products.png
- http://www.buggyonpurpose.com/magento/configurable_products/07-edit_product.png

Comment: See if you are writing those to the database, also enable developer mode and see if you are getting any warnings or errors.

Comment: Your image links are dead

Answer (score 5):

It took a while but finally figured it out. When I created my attributes, in Attribute Properties where it says "Apply To:" I had only assigned it to configurable products, but you must also assign to simple products as well. (or just apply to all)

Keep in mind you will have to recreate your original configurable product before it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have created attributes with options and attribute set.
Can you please createConfigurable product again

1. Manage products -> Add Product select your default attribute set and Configurable product option.
2. The next window will be to choose the attributes that you have have created. 
   Lets say that there are three attributes color, fragrance, and volume as three different attributes and you pick fragrance here to associate the Configurables to the simples which you will be creating.
   After you successfully created the Configurable product.
3. Create simple products based on the same attribute set default
4. you must be able to see all the attributes you created(color, fragrance, and volume).
5. Please pick any option for the Fragrance attribute.
6. Go to the Manage Products ->select to edit the Configurable product you have just created.
7. Go to the "Associated Products" tab and select "Any" from the drop down on the extreme left.
8. You must be able to see the Simple which you have created now
9. you must also be able to see the parent-child linking attribute "fragrance" present above the grid of products.
10. Make sure the simple is in "In stock" before you see whether they appear in front end.

Its not necessary for the attribute to appear in the Configurable product edit page. 
Follow the above steps, hope it will guide you.
Please let me know if you unable to follow any of the above steps.

You can also read the below link, which is very useful to create a config product.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product/

Cheers

Comment: Please see my edit to show the steps I have taken (screen grabs)... which are exactly as you describe since I had followed that guide and other similar guides previously... I have attempted this several times just to make sure I'm doing it right and I don't think its me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

A possible workaround is to add the attributes in the single products and after they become available through the configurable product at "Apply To:".